# .empty() function won't work after loading contents with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multi-level

I did a multilevel ajax call .i.e. make an ajax call and use the id value from the call to make another call... I tried calling a jquery .empty() isn't working for the data generated in the inner ajax call... But when i place the .empty() function on the outer generated element, it worked just fine... How can i fix this issue? This is my code../

```
$(document).on('click', '.stories', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var request = $.ajax({ //first ajax call///
        url: 'includes/functions.php?job=front_title',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'get'
    });

    request.done(function(output) {
        if (output.result === 'success') {
            $('.blog').empty();
            var jsonArray = $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(output.data))).each(function() {
                var id = this.titleID;
                var storyTitle = this.story_view;
                var frontTitle = '<div class="blog-item"><h3>' + storyTitle + '</h3>' + '<img class="img-responsive img-story" src="images/blog/blog1.jpg" width="100%" alt="" />' + '<div class="blog-content"><div class="entry-meta"><h4>Episodes</h4></div>' + '<div class="well" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 5px; width: 105%;">' + '<ul class="tag-cloud stories">';
                var request2 = $.ajax({ ////inner ajax call//////
                    url: 'includes/functions.php?job=story_episodes',
                    cache: false,
                    data: 'id=' + id,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: 'get'
                });

                request2.done(function(output2) {
                    var i = 1;
                    if (output2.result === 'success') {
                        var jsonArray2 = $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(output2.data))).each(function() {
                            var id2 = this.id;
                            var title = this.title;
                            var count = this.episode_count;

                            if (count == 0) {
                                frontTitle += id2;
                            } else if (i % 20 == 0) {
                                frontTitle += '<li data-id="' + id2 + '" id="singleEpisode"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="#story/' + storyTitle + '/' + title + '">' + i + '</a></li></ul><ul class="tag-cloud">';
                            } else {
                                frontTitle += '<li style="margin: 1px" data-id="' + id2 + '" id="singleEpisode"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="#story/' + storyTitle + '/' + title + '">' + i + '</a></li>';
                            }
                            i += 1;
                        })
                    }
                    $('.blog').append(frontTitle);
                    frontTitle += '</ul></div></div>';
                })
            })
        } else {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    });
});
```

I really need help for this, i av been on this for two days now... I would really appreciate the help.. or is there a better way i could do this?

Comment: why you don't use `$('.blog').html("");`

Comment: The `empty` method is where it should be? So this first call is not working, right?

Comment: Yeah... When i check with alert(), it works fine, i mean it gives an alert but doesn't empty the div... I dont really know wat the problem is?

Comment: What is it exactly what you want to do? Clear `.blog` after calling `$('.blog').append(frontTitle)`?

Comment: @shayanypn `.empty()` does the same as `.html("")`. The only difference is readablity

Comment: Instead of using `.empty()` followed by `.append()`, just use `.html()`. That will replace the contents of `blog` with the AJAX results. You only need to use `.append()` if you're adding to `.blog` in a loop.

Comment: Why are you concatenating to `frontTitle` **after** you call `$('.blog').append(frontTitle)`?

Comment: The function lists all the title from the db, and in the within each title div lists all the episodes related to the title... Thats why I used append... Cos its a loop...